# Typescript: 'Promise<any[]>' is not assignable to type

Tags: sql, typescript, type-conversion

My interface:

```js
interface MeetingAttributeRecords {
  branches: Array<Promise<any>>;
  worshipStyles: Array<Promise<any>>;
  accessibilities: Array<Promise<any>>;
}
```

A simplified version of my controller:

```js
export const getAllMeetings = async (req, res) => {
  const meetings = await query(
    `SELECT * FROM meeting;`
  );

  const promises: MeetingAttributeRecords = getMeetingAttributeRecords(meetings);

  Promise.all([
    Promise.all(promises.worshipStyles),
    Promise.all(promises.branches),
    Promise.all(promises.accessibilities)
  ]).then(() => {
    res.json({ meetings: meetings.rows });
  });
};
```

And the utility function that runs some additional queries, returning promises:

```js
export async function getMeetingAttributeRecords(meetings) {

  const branches = await meetings.rows.map(async (meeting) => {
    const branch = await query(
      // SQL CODE
    );
    return meeting.branch = branch.rows;
  });

  const worshipStyles = await meetings.rows.map(async (meeting) => {
    const ws = await query(
      // SQL CODE
    );
    return meeting.worship_style = ws.rows;
  });

  const accessibilities = await meetings.rows.map(async (meeting) => {
    const access = await query(
      // SQL CODE
    );
    return meeting.accessibility = access.rows;
  });

  return [branches, worshipStyles, accessibilities];
}
```

And I'm seeing the following Typescript errors:

```js
[ts]
Type 'Promise<any[]>' is not assignable to type 'MeetingAttributeRecords'.
  Property 'branches' is missing in type 'Promise<any[]>'.
```

I've been scouring the documentation and help articles for a while now, but no dice. Does anyone have insight into this?

Let me know if there are any other details you need!

Answer (score 2):

`getMeetingAttributeRecords` is returning an array instead of a `MeetingAttributeRecords` compatible object.

Changing it to `return {branches, worshipStyles, accessibilities};` should do the trick. (Or at least solve that specific error)

Comment: Oh, wow. Can't believe I didn't notice I had the wrong data type. :D

I've changed the array to an object. But I'm now getting another error: [ts]
Type 'Promise<{branches: any; worshipStyles: any; accessibilities: any; }>' is not assignable to type 'MeetingAttributeRecords'.
  Property 'branches' is missing in type 'Promise<{ branches: any; worshipStyles: any; accessibilities: any; }>'.

Comment: Maybe it's because `getMeetingAttributeRecords` is `async`, so it's returning a promise itself? Does your `const promises` have a `.then` property on it?

Comment: Yes, each of the attributes on getMeetingAttributeRecords is an array of promises. I'm expecting them to resolve in Promise.all() and then fire the res.json()... But I see what you mean - the whole object is also being returned as a single promise!

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much to those who have shared their observations. As Frank Modica noted, I was ultimately returning an object of array of promises as a single promise. So the problem was in the way I was handling that single promise in the route.

Instead of Promise.all, I needed to treat the single promise as a thenable object:

```
const promises = getMeetingAttributeRecords(meetings);

promises.then(() => {
    res.json({meetings: meetings.rows});
});
```

My mistake was thinking that I actually had many promises to resolve, rather than just one!